# Subparts for templates with Meteor & Blaze

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-blaze

Hello I am using Meteor & Blaze.

My routes look like this:

```
FlowRouter.route('/software', {
    name: 'software',
    action(params, queryParams)
    {
        BlazeLayout.render('App_body', {main_content: 'software_page'});
    }
});
```

And in App_body I use main_content (which holds the name of a template) like this:

```
{{> Template.dynamic template=main_content}}
```

But now I realized that I like to insert in App_body more than just "main_content". Is there a way to define subparts for each template, and refer to them, as this would represent my logical connection, which I have.

Answer (score 1):

There's an example at the top of the [blaze-layout](https://github.com/kadirahq/blaze-layout) readme that uses dynamic templates:

html:

```
<template name="layout1">
  {{> Template.dynamic template=top}}
  {{> Template.dynamic template=main}}
</template>

<template name="header">
  <h1>This is the header</h1>
</template>

<template name="postList">
  <h2>This is the postList area.</h2>
</template>

<template name="singlePost">
  <h2>This is the singlePost area.</h2>
</template>
```

Now you can render the layout while feeding in multiple template names in the second parameter which is an object where each key specifies a template name.

js:

```
BlazeLayout.render('layout1', { top: "header", main: "postList" });
```